# react-navigation undefined is not an object (evaluating this_onLayout.bind)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

This error occurs when code that has been running successfully is reexecuted

react-native 0.58
react-navigation:3.11

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import {
  View,
  BackHandler,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
  
import { Provider } from "mobx-react";
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Provider {...store}>
          <AppContainer></AppContainer>
        </Provider>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScene,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      tabBarLabel: '首页',
      tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) => (
          <TabBarItem
              nomalImg={require('./src/img/icon/Home.png')}
              selectedImg={require('./src/img/icon/Home_selected.png')}
              focuesd={focused}
              tintColor={tintColor}
          />
      ),
      tabBarOnPress: () => {
        navigation.navigate('Home', {
          'nowGet': true
        })
      }
    })
  },
  Rank: {
    screen: RankScene,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: '排行榜',
      tabBarLabel: '排行榜',
      tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) => (
          <TabBarItem
              nomalImg={require('./src/img/icon/Rank.png')}
              selectedImg={require('./src/img/icon/Rank_selected.png')}
              focuesd={focused}
              tintColor={tintColor}
          />
      )
    })
  },
},{
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  lazy: true,
  //是否可以滑动切换
  swipeEnabled: false,
  //切换是否有动画
  animationEnabled: false,
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: color.primary,
    inactiveTintColor: color.gray,
    style : {backgroundColor: 'white',fontSize:10}
  }

})

Tab.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  return {
    header:null
  }
}
const Stack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Tab,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    })
  }
}, {
  navigationOptions: {
  },
  initialRouteName: 'Home'
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(Stack)
```

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',"mobx"],
  plugins: [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
      ["@babel/transform-runtime", {
          "helpers": true,
          "regenerator": false
      }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", {"loose":true}]
  ]
};
```

TypeError:undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._onLayout.bind'),
this error is locate at transition(at CardStackTransition.js:55)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mS1G.png)

Comment: could you try `export default  AppContainer = createAppContainer(Stack)` remove class App

Comment: if i remove class App ,i cannot do someting else just like componentWillMount...

Comment: although i did as you said,it does not work

Comment: try reproducing as a snack on https://snack.expo.io